# C++populating base class protected member using derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have something like this:

```
Class Base
{
  public:
    Base();
  protected:
    someType myObject;
}

Class Child:public someNamespace::Base
{
   //constructor
   Child(someType x):myObject(x){}
}
```

Class Child, and Base are in 2 different namespaces...
Compiler complains that my Child class does not have a field called myObject

Anyone know why? Is it because its illegal to populate a Base member from a Child constructor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are initializing your inherited `myObject` in the initialization list. When an object of the derived class is created, before entering the body of the constructor of the derived class the constructor of the base class is called *(by default, if base class has default or no parameter constructor, otherwise you have to explicitly call the constructor in the initialization list)*.

So, when you do :: `Class Child:public someNamespace::Base` your constructor for the base class has not yet been called, which is why your compiler complains ::  *Child class does not have a field called myObject*, that is you are actually trying to assign a value to something which has not yet been declared and defined! It will get defined after the constructor the `Base` class enters its execution.

So, your `Child` class constructor will look something like this ::

```
   Child(someType x) {
      myObject = x;
   }
```

Working ideone link :: http://ideone.com/70kcdC

I found this point missing in the answer above, so I thought it might actually help!

Comment: Ok, you said " when you do :: Class Child:public someNamespace::Base your constructor for the base class has not yet been called" 

The way to fix this issue is to do Assignment within the Child's constructor instead of Child's Initialization list?

Comment: @Telenoobies : yes, because by the time you enter the Child's Constructor body, your Base class members have been created, because the Base class constructor has already completed it's execution, and `myObject` gets defined. When you initialize in the initialization list, the base class object has not been created, that is why the error says *Child class does not have a field called myObject*

Answer (score 4):

You cannot initialize the inherited member like that. Instead, you can give the base class a constructor to initialize that member, then the derived class can call that constructor.

```
class Base
{
  public:
    Base(someType x) : myObject{x} {}
  protected:
    someType myObject;
}

class Child : public Base
{
  public:
    //constructor
    Child(someType x) : Base(x) {}
}
```

In general, a class should be responsible for initializing its own members.

Comment: Ok, make sense. I will give that a try. Thanks

Comment: @Telenoobies: If `myObject` is only accessed within the base class, you should also make it `private`.

Comment: You can also make that Base constructor `protected` so that only derived classes can call it

Comment: Did you change your `Child` constructor to `Child(someType x) : someNamespace::Base(x) {}`?

Comment: Yea.... The base class can have 2 constructors right?
One empty one, and the other that takes someType parameter. They look something like this:

Class Base
{
  public:
    Base::Base();
    Base::Base(SomeType x);
}

Comment: Its fixed! I had to assign the Base class member in the Child's constructor, instead of Child's initialization list. 

Thanks for your help guys.